# I cannot use the > button to view the rest of the columns in the dataframe in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

The button usually allows you to scroll through but its currently working for me. I cannot view columns other than 1-50 without filtering the dataset columns I'd like to view. This is happening with all my datasets.

[image]

Comment: Have you recently updated RStudio? Or have you tried updating RStudio? What is your RStudio version? As this question is purely about an RStudio feature and not about R code, you might get better help searching/posting on the [RStudio Community Forums](https://community.rstudio.com/).

Comment: - Restart Rstudio -Restart PC -Reinstall Rstudio. If in any of these steps your problem is not going away, switch to python.

Comment: that is definitely not a helpful comment, RYann. He asked for help troubleshooting rstudio. "Switch to Python" is obviously an option, but kind of obviously one we do not need to mention.

Comment: Known issue - https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13220

Comment: As @margusl points out, it's an issue with the latest version of RStudio. I reverted back to an older version and it hasn't been an issue since.